# Faithful flatness and non-commutative algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, flatness

$\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}$When dealing with commutative algebras, a usefull criterion for faithful flatness is the following:

Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a morphism of commutative algebras. Then $f$ is faithfully flat if and only if $f$ is flat and the associated map $f^*:\Spec(B)\rightarrow \Spec(A)$ is surjective.

This criterion follows from the fact that a flat map between local rings is faithfully flat, and that a module is zero if and only if its localizations at prime ideals are zero.

Now, what happens if $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily commutatitve? In this situation, localization does not work as easily, and one cannot define the spectrum of a non-commutative algebra (at least in a naïve way). Hence, the criterion above will not hold in this setting.

So, apart from checking the definition, are there any general criteria to show that a flat map of non-commutative algebras is faithfully flat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple criterion. I learned from Jacob Lurie's paper [Tannaka Duality for Geometric Stacks](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412266), Lemma 5.5. His argument works, but since his statement does not cover the current situation, let me phrase an adapted statement and transcribe his proof, hopefully correct.

> Let $f\colon A\to B$ be a map of associative rings. Let $A''$ denote the cokernel of $f$ as an abelian group, which carries a canonical $A$-$A$-bimodule structure. Then the map $f$ exhibits $B$ as a faithfully flat left $A$-module if and only if
>
> 1. the map $f$ is injective, and
> 2. the left $A$-module $A''$ is flat.

**Proof.** We start with assuming the injectivity of $f$ and the flatness of $A''$. Then the left $A$-module $B$ is an extension of $A''$ by $A$. Since flat modules are stable under extensions, the left $A$-module $B$ is flat. For every right $A$-module $N$, we have an exact sequence
$$\DeclareMathOperator\Tor{Tor}
0=\Tor^A_1(N,A'')\to N\to N\otimes_AB\to N\otimes_AA''\to0.
$$
If $N\otimes_AB=0$, then $N=0$. It follows that the left $A$-module $B$ is faithfully flat.

Now we assume that the map $f$ exhibits $B$ as a faithfully flat left $A$-module. Then the map $B=A\otimes_AB\xrightarrow{f\otimes1}B\otimes_AB$ of abelian groups is injective, since it admits a retract given by the multiplication map $B\otimes_AB\to B$. Since the left $A$-module $B$ is faithfully flat, it follows that the map $f$ of right $A$-modules is injective.

It remains to see that the left $A$-module $A''$ is flat. Let $N'\to N$ be any injective map of right $A$-modules. We have to see that the map $N'\otimes_AA''\to N\otimes_AA''$ of right $A$-modules is injective, which is equivalent to the injectivity of $N'\otimes_AA''\otimes_AB\to N\otimes_AA''\otimes_AB$ by faithful flatness of the left $A$-module $B$. We now examine the short exact sequence
$$
0\to B=A\otimes_AB\xrightarrow{f\otimes1}B\otimes_AB\to A''\otimes_AB\to0
$$
of left $A$-modules (by left flatness of $B$). As previously, the map $f\otimes1$ of left $A$-module admits a retract given by the multiplication $B\otimes_AB\to B$ which is also left $A$-linear. It follows that the left $A$-module $A''\otimes_AB$ is a direct summand of the left $A$-module $B\otimes_AB$. Since the left $A$-module $B\otimes_AB$ is flat, so is the left $A$-module $A''\otimes_AB$, and the result follows.

Comment: The idea that $B/A$ detects faithful flatness is already (implicit) in Serre's GAGA.

Answer (score 7):

If $A$ happens to be (left) Noetherian then to show $f$ makes $B$ a faithfully flat right $A$-module it is enough to check that $B\otimes_A S\neq 0$ for every *simple* (left) $A$-module $S$ since, in that case, any $A$-module $M$ has a simple subquotient $S$ and $B\otimes_A S$ will be a subquotient of $B\otimes_A M$. This is because if $N$ is a submodule of $M$ then $B\otimes_A N \to B\otimes_A M$ is an injection and if $S$ is a simple quotient of $N$ then $B\otimes_A N\to B\otimes_A S$ is a surjection.